# Bootstrap style not integrating with Laravel 9

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, laravel-9

I'm using bootstrap for styling may Laravel 9. I tried different types of referencing. I'm using this right now:

my stylesheet:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/assets/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css')}}">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Nunito:200,200i,300,300i,400,400i,600,600i,700,700i,800,800i,900,900i&amp;display=swap">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset('/assets/fonts/fontawesome-all.min.css')}}">
```

my js:

```
<script src="{{ asset('js/bootstrap.min.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/chart.min.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/bs-init.js') }}" defer></script>
    <script src="{{ asset('js/theme.js') }}" defer></script>
```

my folders:
[resources](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ieucu.png)

Comment: L9 comes with tailwind out of the box; have you installed the bootstrap first

Comment: are you accessing through the php artisan serve command ?  or using localhost or any server URl.

Comment: @AliRaza yess i installed it

Comment: @JayeshNai yes im accessing through php artisan serve

Answer (score 0):

The asset only provides a lesson on the public folder. No need if you are using views with resources.

Comment: I moved my css and js into public folder, it worked. Is it the right way?